# How do I change the screensaver password using Linux Mint 19?

Tags: password

I am runnning Linux Mint 19.0 "Tara" on my new HP 17-ca0010nr laptop. Now I used the

> sudo passwd

command to change my password but for some reason when I close the lid and the screensaver starts, it won't accept anything other than my old password. How do I fix this? I want a master password like I had before.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `sudo passwd`, you change the password of the root user. Your screensaver wants the password of the user you logged in as, and if that is root, you're doing something seriously wrong.

If you want to change your own password, use `passwd` *without sudo* in a terminal.